# How to see (in)dependence of random variables based on their joint density

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

[image]

This is a valid joint pdf.

I just want to know if X1 and X2 are dependent or independent rvs ? Why ?

Thank you for your help.

Is there a way of seeing this without  computing the marginal density of X1 ?

PS: If you suggest that they are INdependent, how do you explain the fact that the joint pdf cannot be factored into seperate functions containing each rv alone ?

Comment: Duplicate of:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103444/quickbut-weird-question-on-two-random-variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easy to see. The joint density $f_{X_1,X_2}$ is not a product $f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)=g(x_1)h(x_2)$ hence $(X_1,X_2)$ is not independent.

To see that the identity $f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)=g(x_1)h(x_2)$ is impossible, check for example that
$$
f_{X_1,X_2}(1,1)f_{X_1,X_2}(2,2)\ne f_{X_1,X_2}(1,2)f_{X_1,X_2}(2,1).
$$
Likewise, for every $x_1\ne x_2$,
$$
f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_1)f_{X_1,X_2}(x_2,x_2)\ne f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)f_{X_1,X_2}(x_2,x_1),
$$
since the ratio
$$
\frac{f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_1)f_{X_1,X_2}(x_2,x_2)}{f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)f_{X_1,X_2}(x_2,x_1)}
$$
is
$$
\exp\left(-1+\frac{x_1}{2x_2}+\frac{x_2}{2x_1}\right)=\exp\left(-\frac12\left(\sqrt{\frac{x_1}{x_2}}-\sqrt{\frac{x_2}{x_1}}\right)^2\right)\lt1.
$$
Note finally (but this is not necessary to solve the question) that $(X_1,X_2)$ coincides in distribution with $(8UV,4V)$, where $(U,V)$ are i.i.d. standard exponential random variables. Then a shortcut to disprove independence would be to note that
$$
E(X_1X_2)-E(X_1)E(X_2)=16E(U)\mathrm{var}(V)\ne0.
$$

Comment: thank you for your detailed reply. If I am asked to compute the conditional density of X1 given X2=x2, What is the support of X1 ?

Comment: The support of $(X_1,X_2)$ is a product $A_1\times A_2$ hence the support of $X_i$ is $A_i$.

Comment: I've improved the question, could you take a look ? Especially what is the parameter of the conditional density ?

Comment: And modifying completely the scope of a question after answers get posted is not the way the site functions. New question? Then new post!

Comment: And crossposting on several SE sites is explicitely discouraged as well. Why did you do it?

Comment: I've deleted the same one could you please help me with this one ?

Comment: I just did, no? And thoroughly, I believe...

Comment: Could you please take a look at the new question again sorry about double posting it ans wasting your time :(